# About the bash shell for Makefile

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

As I very new to bash shell script, I could not understand the Makefile that I am using for compiling some program.

Could you explain the meaning of '$@' and '$<' in the following source code? Thank you in advance.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -I /usr/local/include/boost-1_37/ -g
LDFLAGS=-L /usr/local/lib
SOURCES=cluster.cpp test.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=k-means

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)


$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o **$@**

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) **$<** -o **$@**

clean:
    rm -fr *.o *~ $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: You should start reading the man pages. It is all explained in there... So start by typing: `man make` If that is not detailed enough, try the info pages. You guess it: `info make`...

Comment: Two things to keep in mind: Makefiles are not written in pure shell script, and by default a Makefile is written in `sh`, not `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) in GNU make manual:

> `$@`
>
> The file name of the target of the rule. If the target is an archive member, then `$@` is the name of the archive file. In a
>   pattern rule that has multiple targets (see Introduction to Pattern
>   Rules), `$@` is the name of whichever target caused the rule's recipe
>   to be run.
>
> `$<`
>
> The name of the first prerequisite. If the target got its recipe from an implicit rule, this will be the first prerequisite added by the implicit rule (see Implicit Rules).

Answer (score 0):

A great book to read for this kind of thing is: http://www.amazon.co.uk/21st-Century-Tips-New-School/dp/1449327141